# Problems with commands separating when remote ssh for centos 7 only

Tags: bash, shell, centos

So I can run this code remotely on Rocky/centos 8 and above and it works. But when I run this code against a Centos 7 host I get ip command not found as it seems to be separating the ip route command. Does anyone have an idea? Kind of stumped here.

```
get_subnet_and_gateway() {
    server_address=$1
    username=$2

    # Fetch default gateway
    gateway=$(ssh "$username"@"$server_address" "ip route | grep 'default via' | awk '{print \$3}' | awk 'NR==1'")

    # Fetch subnet
    subnet=$(ssh "$username"@"$server_address" "ip route | grep 'src' | awk '{print \$1}' | awk 'NR==1'")

    echo "$subnet"
    echo "$gateway"
}

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <HOST or IP>"
    exit 1
fi

server_address=$1
username='user'

subnet_and_gateway=$(get_subnet_and_gateway "$server_address" "$username")
if [ -n "$subnet_and_gateway" ]; then
    echo "$subnet_and_gateway"
    exit 0
fi
```

[image]

Expect to return the same as it does for rocky/centos8

Comment: "*it seems to be separating the ip route command*" -- not any differently than CentOS 8 does.  The command name is [`ip`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html).  The `route` part is a command-line argument.  And the `ip` command is not available by default on CentOS 7.  The old school alternative to `ip route` that you would use on CentOS 7 is [`route`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/route.8.html).  The output format will differ somewhat, I believe.

Comment: This must be a rocky 8 difference, then. When I do which IP on Centos 7, I get /sbin/ip. I can run the ip route command in the script at the command line with no issues on Centos 7, just not from the script. The script runs fine on rocky 8.

Comment: If the command is not found despite being present on the system, then yours is almost surely a path issue.  Apparently, `/sbin` is not in the path for the user as whom you are connecting, when you connect as you are doing.  It would be all-around better in a case such as this to invoke the command via an absolute path.

Comment: You are right. I added the full path, and it works. Thank you! An absolute path is always best practice. Thank you again.